# print the value of last not null column in awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file like below and want to print the value of last not null column in awk.

**Input**

```
a|||||||
a|b|d|||||
c|d|e|f||||
f|e||||||
f|e|g|||||
```

**Output:**

```
a
d
f
e
g
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: let's say this file is having 24 fixed columns then trying `awk -F'|' '{ for (i = 24; i <=24; i--)  { if($i!="") print $i; break; }}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F '|' '{sub(/[|]+$/, ""); print $NF}' file
```

**Details:**

- `sub(/[|]+$/, "")` function strips out all empty `|`s before line end
- `print $NF` prints the last field which is not empty

```
a
d
f
e
g
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution

```
awk -F'|' '{ for (i = NF; i > 0 ; i--) if($i!="") {print $i; break;} }' <file name>
```

It works